# PHP / MySQL: How to call a col in a MySQL-Result with more than one table?

Tags: php, mysql

If I have a Select Statement like this:

```
SELECT T1.TEXT, T2.FIELD FROM TABLE1 T1, TABLE2 T2 WHERE T1.ID = T2.ID
```

Then i use it with mysql_query and fetch it with mysql_fetch_object.

How can i access now the fields? $fetched->T1.TEXT doesn't work...

thx for help

**UPDATE 2013**: This question is quite old, but the correct and simplest way is to give every field an alias in the select statement, so they are unique. Sample:

```
SELECT T1.TEXT AS MYTEXT, T2.FIELD AS MYFIELD FROM TABLE1 T1, TABLE2 T2 WHERE T1.ID = T2.ID
```

PHP:

```
mysql_connect('host','user','pass');
mysql_select_db('mydb');
$resource = mysql_query(/* the query again */);
$firstrow = mysql_fetch_object($resource);
$text = $firstrow->MYTEXT;
$field = $firstrow->MYFIELD;
```

Comment: I think it won't work because if I'd select T1.TEXT and T2.TEXT, this won't work.

Comment: why dont you add an alias to your field eg `SELECT T1.TEXT as t1_text, T2.FIELD as t2_field FROM TABLE1 T1, TABLE2 T2 WHERE T1.ID = T2.ID` and then try $fetched->t1_text or $fetched->t2_field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at this

```
mysql_connect("hostname", "user", "password");
mysql_select_db("mydb");
$result = mysql_query("select user_id,fullname from mytable");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($result)) {
    echo $row->user_id;
    echo $row->fullname;
}
mysql_free_result($result);
```

More [in php manual about mysql-fetch-object](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-object.php)

Comment: This works, but don't make the mistake that so many people (including me) make when starting with PHP/MYSQL... use prepared statements  http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Answer (score 1):

You can see what fields are in your object by doing this:

```
var_dump($fetched);
```

You will probably see the field $fetched->TEXT.

(assuming you are using php)

Answer (score 0):

try this ->

```
$fetched->{T1.TEXT}
```